# Read a function template in main?

Tags: c++, templates

Well I'm not a very experience programmer in C++ (still learning) I know all the C library though.

I came up with a question. What the following template means and how I should call the split function from main?

```
template <typename T, size_t len> 
pair<size_t,size_t> 
split(T const (& arr)[len]) { 
//blah blah .. code ... blah blah 
}
```

I know I need an array but how I pass it in the template? What arguments do I need?

here is the array I created in main

```
int N = 10;
int *array = new int[N];
//now I use I/O to pass the numbers in the array, but say we have them

 //Now I should call the template. I need to pass the array
   //to make the process?

 delete [] array;
```

Comment: don't forget to look at `std::vector`, and `std::array` before using C-style arrys

Comment: well I only need to use the function which is writen by my candidate. I use C but now I need to use C++

Answer (score 2):

You need just array on stack, not on heap. Size of array should be known at compile-time.

```
const size_t N = 10;
int array[N];
// fill array
split(array);
```

Comment: but I want to pass the elemnts from a file as well as to read the size of the array. Can I use vector insteed? Any other way?

Comment: @Bill rewrite function split. It works only with array, that size is known on compile-time.

Comment: how? I don;t know. As I say in my above comment I only need to use the function which is writen by my candidate. I use C but now I need to use C++. Can you help me to use the function for arrays in the heap?

Comment: @Bill it's actually another question and not for stackoverlow I think.

Comment: @Bill no, `split` as written cannot be used on arrays on the heap.  It was written to take only literal compile-time fixed size arrays, not dynamic sized arrays, for whatever reason.

Comment: please help me! I don't have time and I can't learn all the C++ in 2 days!

Comment: @Bill you cannot use something else, without function `split` rewriting.